# Prevent multiple execution of a ReactiveCommand (CreateAsyncTask)

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

Is it possible to prevent multiple execution of a ReactiveCommand.

Here is the 'simple' code I use:

The command is created:

```
this.LoadCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(
            async _ => await this._dataService.Load(),
            RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler);
```

After I add the subscription to the command:

```
this.LoadCommand.Subscribe(assets => ...);
```

And finally, I execute the command:

```
this.LoadCommand.ExecuteAsyncTask();
```

If I call the ExecuteAsyncTask multiple time at several location, I would like that any subsequent calls wait for the first one to finish.

EDIT:
Here is the complete code for the Subscribe method:

```
    this.LoadCommand.Subscribe(assets =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background, 
                    new Action(() => this.Assets.Clear()));

                foreach (Asset asset in assets)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.Background, 
                        new Action<Asset>(a =>
                        {
                            this.Assets.Add(a);
                        }), asset);
                }
            });
```

Thanks,

Adrien.

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for the first one to finish" ? the code within Subscribe is already "waiting" (no concurrent execution), is it about the async part ?

Comment: I doubt the "no concurrent" part. Here is why. I execute 5 times directly the code `LoadCommand.ExecuteAsyncTask()`. Inside the `Subscribe()` of the command I clear a `List` and add items into it. At the end, I get 5 times the same images.

Comment: As @Gluck pointed out, `Subscribe` is always serialized. So probably the behavior is defined by `_dataService.Load()`

Comment: The issue is likely in another part of your code then, can you post more of it ?

Comment: The `_dataService.Load()` return a collection of items. In the subscribe I clear a List of my ViewModel and add the items again. If I replace the `_dataService.Load()` by `new List<Item>() { new Item(), new Item() }`, I got the same behavior. There is no other code, it's simple as that ...

Comment: I added the complete code for the subscribe method, perhaps the error is in there ...

Comment: Don't see the reason, InvokeAsync would break the serializing of the actions, but Invoke shouldn't. Maybe post more of your code ? (e.g. any chance this.Assets gets shared by multiple commands ?)

Comment: There is nothing more. I posted all my code. Asset is only be used in the subscribe and in the view for the binding so it is not shared between other commands.

Comment: Here is a sample that makes exactly what I don't want to : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E1F246570537221C!321477&authkey=!AAUtzqd2yFBIEz0&ithint=file%2czip

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your sample application, and was able to fix it.  Here's my 2 cents:

1) I took out the `Rx.TaskpoolScheduler` parameter in your command creation.  That tells it to deliver the results using that scheduler, and I think you want to stick to delivering results on the UI thread.

2) Since by making this change you are now running your Subscribe logic on the UI thread, you don't need to deal with all that Invoking.  You can access the collection directly:

```
this.LoadCommand.Subscribe(dataCollection =>
                                      {
                                          DataCollection.Clear();
                                          DataCollection.AddRange(dataCollection);
                                      });
```

Making just those 2 changes caused it to "work".

I'm no expert, but what I think was happening is that the actual ReactiveCommand "LoadCommand" you had was immediately returning and delivering results on various TaskPool threads.  So it would never allow concurrency within the Command itself, which is by design.  However the subscribes, I think since each was coming in on a different thread, were happening concurrently (race).  So all the clears occurred, then all the adds.

By subscribing and handling all on the same thread you can avoid this, and if you can manage it on the UI thread, you won't need to involve Invoking to the Dispatcher.

Also, in this particular situation using the Invoke on the Dispatcher with the priority `DispatcherPriority.Background` seems to execute things in a non-serial fashion, not sure exactly the order, but it seemed to do all the clears, then the adds in reverse order (I incremented them so I could tell which invocation it was).  So there is definitely something to be said for that.  FWIW changing the priority to `DispatcherPriority.Send` kept it serial and displayed the "expected" behavior.  That being said, I still prefer avoiding Invoking to the Dispatcher altogether, if you can.

Comment: Your solution works but it blocks the UI (this was my first attempt ...). Using the `Rx.TaskpoolScheduler` allows me to load asynchronously the items of the list without blocking the UI. It also allows me to "incrementally load" the items in the list control.

Comment: Well, you can still load them async in a background thread.  It's blocking as the list is populated and draws them?  Do you virtualize your list control?  At some point it has to display on the ui thread.  Have you used `.SuppressChangeNotifications()` on your reactivelist as you make the changes?  If you need to do it your way, I guess you will need to use some sort of lock or concurrent queue due to the multiple threads.

Comment: I do load the data in a background thread. It's exactly why I'm using the `Rx.TaskpoolScheduler`. The `.SuppressChangeNotifications()` is doing nothing (I already tested that). BTW I don't mind using a lock or something else but the `Subscribe` method does not manage concurrent execution with the `Rx.TaskpoolScheduler`. It is either by design or a bug or people don't understand correctly how it's suppose to works ...

Comment: Getting confused about your "load data" terminology, I was referring to it within your asynctask, assuming you are using a background thread in your dataservice.load.  You are using it to mean run the subscription logic on taskpool threads.  I don't think there is anything in the subscribe method to prevent concurrent execution on different threads.  Could you just add that logic to your Async Task, and not do anything in the subscribes?  That way you get concurrency protection.